# Referencing answer given on SE

Tags: discussion, comment, asking-questions

Recently I asked the math.SE community my first question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392027/expectation-of-int-0t-w-s2-dw-s-integral-of-square-of-brownian-wrt-to-bro)), after a few minutes an experienced used resolved my issue with a smooth answer.

But my problem is that this question was derived from an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100345/stochastic-integral/100356#100356) to another question from another user. What I first tried is asking for explanations in the post itself and not spam the server with derivatives of questions. Yet I got this [SE-limitation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). And I decided it is there for a reason and that newcomers should answer and ask before commenting, which makes sense somehow. So I created my question.

Immediate backlash followed in the comments, so here are my questions :

- As a newcomer I only bothered to read the "[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)". But this guide does not seem to tackle the issue. One needs to do a google search and find this "[How to mention/tag any user in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97474)". Should I really have gone that far before asking a question?
- Second issue is that I have the impression that I tried my best, but the critics came from a moderator, or at least someone with 3k+ rep that has some moderation privileges (who is supposed to know the mechanics of the site more than I do). Hence I have a tendency to believe the argument from authority and that I was in the wrong. But as I defended myself, I said I did link the answer (a shortened reference, I found info somewhere, I link the info, clearly not a reference for publication standards) and after the first wave of critic, I edited and added the specific names of the authors. But clearly that was not sufficient. What could I have done more? Should I have farmed more reputation before asking my question? Not asking my question at all? I am still confused at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108)

Comment: Just a minor correction - as far as I can see, there were no comments on the linked post made by moderators. (You can find list of moderators of this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).)

Comment: It looks to me like you did your best in the end.  I frequently link to other people's Questions here on the site for the sake of supplying building blocks to be found in older Answers.  The site encourages one to do so for the sake of supplying context if a related Question is being asked.  No disrespect to my colleagues is intended.

Comment: Welcome to math se. I think you've acted quite reasonably through this, and maybe even gotten an answer to your question on the mathematics. . Keep asking (and answering). Pretty soon you'll have enough reputation to make this question here moot.

Comment: In line 2 do you mean "user" instead of "used"?

Comment: Sometimes people just jump to conclusions despite your best efforts. I'm probably guilty of that myself, assuming that new users just want someone to do their homework for them.