# Duplicate question with a not satisfying answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

What should I do if I have a question that's been already asked and answered years ago but I don't get the answer? Should I ask a new question and link the old one?

Comment: Is the problem that the answer is unclear, or that the previous question didn't get any answers at all?

Comment: @CarlMummert This is the question I'm talking about:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418494/when-a-dihedral-groups-is-nilpotent
As you can see there is no answer at all, but there is a useful hint in the comments. The problem is I don't get it.

Comment: That question is pretty bad!  It also seems to be a duplicate of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834966/is-the-dihedral-group-d-n-nilpotent-solvable .  Does the answer in that second question help you more?

Comment: @Carl Yes I found that question too, but I don't get the answer.

Comment: In that case, if you have questions about specific parts of the answer, you can ask a question about those parts. Like you said, you'd want to link to the original question, and explain what exactly was not clear to you in the original answer.  Avoid just saying "I don't understand", which is too general for someone to answer - explain the specific part of the answer that you don't understand.  Good luck!

Comment: @Carl Ok then, I'll try to think a bit more about it and eventually ask a new question. Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer and the questions in the "linked" column there