# If you had a question about someone's answer to not your question, is it better to comment or make a new question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If you had a question about someone's answer to not your question from 7 years ago by an active user, is it better to comment or make a new question? The problem is they have no incentive to answer your comment but they're the expert at answering that question supposedly and making a new question might invite someone who hasn't thought about your question as much.

Comment: If they are active they might answer your question. Did you try?

Comment: Related: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108) (some other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108) might be worth having a look,too).