# If I have a question that has already been answered, but I don't understand the answer and the thread seems to be dead, how do I ask?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, answers, asking-questions

My post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736982/if-r-is-a-reduced-noetherian-ring-and-u-subset-r-is-a-multiplicatively-clos?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed. I have the same question as another user but I do not understand the accepted answer. To me, it appears incomplete. It is missing details which I do not know how to fill in.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your own post (which is not closed at this time) to be more self-contained.  It is good that you pinned down the point in the argument where you find a gap, but the problem setup would ideally not require following the link to the older Question.   If you like I will try to make a minimal edit for this purpose.

Comment: In this specific instance, your question was closed as a duplicate of the linked question. This is clearly not the case, so you could have posted a request to reopen it in the appropriate meta thread [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/10513). (Possibly the person who closed it would rather you had commented beneath the answer asking for clarification though, as per Asaf's answer here. But I am just guessing, as they didn't comment.)

Comment: See also: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108).. (And some of [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108)) might be of interest too.

Answer (score 7):

Steps towards a solution:

1. If the user is somewhat active (e.g. visited the site in the last month or so), leave a comment asking for clarification and wait a few days. I get such comments every now and then, and that's fine.
2. If the first step failed, ask a new question. Put a link to the question, quote the answer, set up the whole context, and explain *what is missing* for you. Wait for an answer.
3. If the second step failed, study harder until you can answer your own question.

Comment: Surely setting a bounty comes before doing actual *work*?!?

Comment: [I am serious, and don't call me Shirley.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM2K7sV-K74)