# how and where you can ask for clarification of a complicated answer

Tags: discussion

I don't fully understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712030/741129), how and where is it better for me to ask a question with a request to explain?

Comment: The user who posted that answer is still active on the site....why not just leave a comment there?

Comment: [math.meta.se]: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108) (and [other linked posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108)) might be of interst, too. [meta.se]: [What should I do if I want more clarifications about an answer posted on an old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110216)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks. I'll use [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110225/642272) as a guide

Comment: the only thing is how long to wait for an answer in the comments, I think, if in a day I do not receive any signs of an answer in the comments, then I will ask a new question with a request to explain

Comment: One tip: in the future, refer to answers you struggle to understand as "complicated" or "very difficult" or "beyond my level of understanding", rather than as "complex", because "complex" might be misunderstood, in mathematics, as as involving the Complex Numbers, or Complex Analysis.

Comment: @amWhy, considered and corrected :)

Comment: @amWhy - Which is why my brother pointed and laughed at my text book that had the title "Basic Complex Analysis". As he said, "which is it, basic or complex?".

Comment: Good question, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC ;D

Comment: I have commented below the answer, please ask a new question and leave a comment to Pavel at the answer so he himself can have a go at explaining it if need be.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon, thanks for the concern, but I figured it out on my own

Comment: In this case, such a factor arises that in order to ask a good question, you try to find out more information about the problem that interests you, in the end, you yourself answer the question.

And if you ask a bad question, without preparation, then you are more likely to get downvotes, and not an answer.

Comment: Moreover, comments are poorly suited for a detailed answer / question (due to the impossibility of a line break), therefore it is better to immediately ask a well-prepared question than to try to find out something in the comments

Comment: @0dminnimda You can do this : post the question and answer it yourself. Post it as a proper question with context (your background, link to the answer etc. is good enough) and answer the question as if it were someone else's question and not your own. That is a good contribution. I can understand your dilemma, but there are many things other than an attempt that qualify as context : your background, source of the problem, any hints you were given, similar questions you've seen and so on. Without attempting the question you have good context then.

Comment: Very helpful suggestion, @TeresaLisbon !  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, I recommended this to a few users and even checked on their question-and-answer posts once they had made it. It is useful both in framing a question for someone else, and answering the question as if you were addressing another person's question, so you get this double-sided perspective of "why was it asked" and "how to do it", which is never the case when you are either the asker or the answerer (as is usually the case).