# Duplicate question doubt

Tags: discussion

I want to know an answer and concept of a question but it's similar version has been asked about 4 times before atleast 3 to 4 years ago. I have been unable to understand the answer given as well as the try the question asker has given. My approach is a bit different also in trying the problem. So if I comment in those questions will I be able to get my answer or will I ask another question. The questions has been asked during 2015–18.

Comment: Related: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108). (Maybe some [discussions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108) might be of interest, too.) I will point out that there are also [various chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814) on this site - it's possible that you might bet help with in getting to understand some answer existing on the site.

Comment: Leaving a comment on an old question is a long shot. It's quite likely no one will see it. Sometimes people comment on my old answers though and I respond. It's a toss up whether the answerer/asker is still active.

Comment: It's better if you ask another question on this topic. Also provide the link to the similar question in that new question, so that I can see who is the OP / participants on the post and tell you if they will reply or not. My guess : probably not.